# Getting an error while pushing the code to repository from command line

Tags: github, azure-devops

devops>git push -u origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/SSN137-Ravi/DevOps.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com

This is the error i am getting while pushing the code, Can anyone explain what can be done here. TIA

Comment: Hi Ravi, welcome to StackOverFlow, for improved clarity, it would be better to move the error explanation to the top of the question. Also, you may want to use the code format to improve the readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following command to your command line:

```
http version:

git config --global --unset http.proxy

https version:

git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

The `--unset` flag can fix the issue where Git will attempt to establish a connection through an invalid proxy configuration (i.e. the user is actually not behind a proxy), which causes Git operations to error out.